# Traveling to non-EU countries during a 1-month stay in an EU country

Tags: visas, europe, spain, turkey, invitation-letters

My family will travel from Peru to Spain. Visa is not required but I will prepare an invitation letter for their travel.

While they are here in Spain, we will travel to Turkey for a week (Turkish visa will be obtained). I wonder if they would have trouble entering back to Spain or not. Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: It is just me, or an invitation letter seems strange? I do not think there are problem: you are doing tourism in an other continent, you will not stay in EU too much. Probably by having ready the return (to Peru) tickets will help

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi I think the OP is in Spain and the family in Peru, hence the invitation letter

Comment: I do not understand the down vote. It is a legit question (especially considering people traveling from other continents, and seldom)